# Algorithm for Solving a Linear Combination?

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I have run into the following problem that I need to solve in a project that I'm working on:

Given some number of vectors v_i (in the math sense), and a target vector H, compute a linear combination of the vectors v_i that most closely matches the target vector H, with the constraint that the coefficients must be in [0, 1].

I do not know much about what kind of algorithms / math should be used to approach such a problem. Any prods in the right general direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you write your mathematical solution ?

Comment: Oh, by formulate I do not mean solve!  I do not know how to solve the general case, which is the problem.

I can solve the case in which we have at least 3 linearly-independent vectors (not taking into account constraints) (note that I am working in 3-space). But this does not necessarily yield the optimal combination. By optimal I mean minimizing the difference between the target vector and the linear combination.  The real question for me is how to solve it "optimally" in the general case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: @starblue I don't think this is a linear programming problem.

Comment: @Chris Taylor The solution space is linear, but the standard objective function (least squares) is nonlinear, so you are right.

Answer (score 2):

It's a constrained least square problem. Basically you want to solve the optimization problem:

```
  argmin ||Ax-H||
    x
  s.t.  0<=x_j<=1
```

where `x=(x_1, ..., x_j, ..., x_n)` consists the coefficients you are seeking, and a column of `A` corresponds to a vector v_i.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to solve in the least squares sense, then you have a quadratic programming problem. For example, say that your set of vectors is

```
x1 = 1 2 3]'    x2 = [3 2 1]'
```

and your target vector is

```
H = [1 -1 1]'
```

Then you can create the matrix whose columns are your vectors:

```
A = [1 3;
     2 2;
     3 1]
```

and the thing you are trying to minimize is

```
norm(A*x - H) = (A*x - H)' * (A*x - H) = x' * (A'*A) * x - (2*H'*A) * x + const
```

If you define

```
B = A' * A
C = -2 * H' * A
```

then you have a problem that can be solved optimally my Matlab's `quadprog` function

```
quadprog(B,C,[],[],[],[],0,1)
ans = 
    0.16667
    0.16667
```

so the optimal solution in this case is

```
1/6 * x1 + 1/6 * x2 = [2/3, 2/3, 2/3]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, now I at least know what type of problem this is!

Answer (score 0):

This is a combinatorial optimization problem. This kind of problems are NP-hard. But I guess for the binary one, there should be polynomial algorithms that can solve, or there may be some relaxation to get an approximate solution. Some googling on "integer programming" may help.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the knowledge.  I actually just solved it adequately using an iterative greedy approach.  I guess the solution isn't optimal but it performs well enough for my application.

Comment: This isn't a combinatorial optimization problem. The weights are intended to be in the interval [0,1] not the set {0,1}.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. If it is in the interval [0,1], then it is constrained least square problem as chaohuang said. The vector norm used in his formulation can be 2 norm (minimize the euclidean distance), if you have a Gaussian noise assumption. The problem can be solved using quadprog in matlab. 1 norm is more robust to other noise models.