# Algorithm to create a vector based puzzle

Tags: algorithm, random, linear-algebra

I am working on a little puzzle-game-project. The basic idea is built around projecting multi-dimensonal data down to 2D. My only problem is how to generate the randomized scenario data. Here is the problem:

I got muliple randomized vectors `v_i` and a target vector `t`, all 2D. Now I want to randomize scalar values `c_i` that:

```
t = sum c_i v_i
```

Because there are more than two `v_i` this is a overdetermined system. I also took care that the linear combination of `v_i` is actual able to reach `t`.

How can I create (randomized) values for my `c_i`?

Edit: After finding [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871577/algorithm-for-solving-a-linear-combination?rq=1) I can additionally state, that it is possible for me also (slightly) change the `v_i`.

All values are based on `double`

Comment: The c_i are integers or reals?

Comment: All values are based on `double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `v_i` form a matrix `V` with 2 rows and n columns, each vector is a column. The coefficients `c_i` form a column vector `c`.  Then the equation can be written in matrix form as

```
V×c = t
```

Now apply a [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to matrix `V`:

```
V = A×D×B
```

with A being an orthogonal 2×2 matrix, D is a 2×n matrix and B an orthogonal n×n matrix.  The original equation now becomes

```
A×D×B×c = t
```

multiply this equation with the inverse of A, the inverse is the same as the transposed matrix `AT`:

```
D×B×c = AT×t
```

Let's introduce new symbols `c'=B×c` and `t'=AT×t`:

```
D×c' = t'
```

The solution of this equation is simple, because Matrix `D` looks like this:

```
u 0 0 0 ...  // n columns
0 v 0 0 ...
```

The solution is

```
c1' = t1' / u
c2' = t2' / v
```

And because all the other columns of `D` are zero, the remaining components `c3'...cn'` can be chosen freely.  **This is the place where you can create random numbers** for `c3'...cn`.  Having vector `c'` you can calculate `c`  as

```
c = BT×c'
```

with `BT` being the inverse/transposed of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the v_i are linearly dependent there are non trivial solutions to 0 = sum l_i v_i.
If you have n vectors you can find n-2 independent such solutions.

If you have now one solution to t = sum c_i v_i you can add any multiple of l_i to c_i and you will still have a solution: c_i' = p l_i + c_i.

For each independent solution of the homogenous problem determine a random p_j and calculate
c_i'' = c_i + sum p_j l_i_j.

Comment: "If you have now one solution to t = sum c_i v_i" is exactly my problem. How do I get one? Your tip for the randomizing with the `l_i`, however, is great. Thanks!

Comment: To get one solution just pick two linearly independent vectors v_i and solve the 2x2 system of linear equations.